# Data are not retriving in recycler view from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Only some of the data is displayed in my `RecyclerView`, and the data that is displayed is not displayed in order. Also the info in `RecyclerView` changes automatically while scrolling.

This is my DatabaseHandler.java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MOBILE_NO + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_HOSPITAL_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DIAGNOSIS + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TREATMENT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE1 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE2 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE3 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE4 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE5 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            + KEY_MEDICINE6 + " TEXT DEFAULT NULL"
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}
```

//to store the sqlite data

```
  public List<UserInfo> getAllData() {
    List<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    UserInfo bean = null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index0 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MOBILE_NO);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DIAGNOSIS);

        String date = cursor.getString(index0);
        String mobile_no = cursor.getString(index1);
        String heading = cursor.getString(index2);
        bean = new UserInfo(date,mobile_no,heading);
        list.add(bean);
    }



    return list;


}
```

this is my `fragment.class`

```
public class My_Health extends Fragment {

DatabaseHandler db;
public String mobile_no;

protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    db= new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
     mobile_no = this.getArguments().getString("MOBILE_NO");



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_home);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeCardAdapter(db.getAllData(), R.layout.cardview_home));

    Log.d("mylog", db.getAllData().toString());




    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.addrecordfab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRecord.class);
            intent.putExtra("MOBILE_NO",mobile_no);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

the result of log

```
11-20 11:16:47.689 31511-31511/com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot D/mylog: [com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@3a6b1a1, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@1b9edfc6, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@3f7cb87, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@21eefab4, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@1e5bc6dd, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@f993252, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@efb9923, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@1ddb0e20, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@152f3d9, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@974219e, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@6e4a47f, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@12b2ec4c, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@8f5f495, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@17cb9aa, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@2629099b, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@9488138, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@348e4511, com.rashim12000.waytofreedom.swasthyatipot.Adapter.UserInfo@35c4c676]
```

Comment: Please show the codes on how you implement the `RecyclerView`

Comment: what getAllData() returns ? log its value. and let us know

Comment: @cw fei   i have added  codes

Comment: @Vivid Vervet  i have added logs

Comment: why are you using two recyclerview?

Comment: i removed it and then ??

Comment: everything looks fine to me, maybe you should post your adapter class as well

Comment: when i log the values everything is correct by while displaying it showing limited no. of data and unordered

Comment: I added `ID field` and it worked normally.